# How do I convert this test rule to JUnit5?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I have some custom rule using junit4 which I would like to convert to junit5. However I'm not able to find good documentation on migrating a MethodRule implementation other than that I should be using junit5 extension instead of rule.

```
public class MyRule implements MethodRule {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyRule.class);

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    public @interface MyAnnotation { }

    @Override
    public Statement apply(final Statement statement, final FrameworkMethod frameworkMethod, final Object o) {
        Statement result = statement;
        if (hasMyAnnotation(frameworkMethod)) {
                result = new Statement() {
                    @Override
                    public void evaluate() {
                        LOGGER.info("Skipping test");
                    }
                };
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static boolean hasMyAnnotation(final Annotatable frameworkMethod) {
        return frameworkMethod.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class) != null;
    }
```

My class is using junit4 `Statement`, `FrameworkMethod` etc to find out if my method has an annotation... then to skip it. How can I convert this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1, Disable test with custom annotation**

JUnit 5 provides a type of extension that can control whether or not a test should be run. This is defined by implementing the [ExecutionCondition](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-conditions) interface.

Extension implementation:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ConditionEvaluationResult;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExecutionCondition;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;
import org.junit.platform.commons.logging.Logger;
import org.junit.platform.commons.logging.LoggerFactory;
import org.junit.platform.commons.util.AnnotationUtils;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement;

public class SkipConditionExtension implements ExecutionCondition {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SkipConditionExtension.class);

    @Override
    public ConditionEvaluationResult evaluateExecutionCondition(ExtensionContext context) {
        AnnotatedElement element = context.getElement().orElse(null);

        if (hasMyAnnotation(element, MyAnnotation.class)) {
            LOGGER.info(() ->"Skipping test");
            return ConditionEvaluationResult.disabled(String.format("Skipped test: %s by @MyAnnotation", element));
        }

        return ConditionEvaluationResult.enabled("Test enabled");
    }

    private <T extends Annotation>  boolean hasMyAnnotation(final AnnotatedElement element, Class<T> annotation) {
        return element != null && AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(element, annotation).isPresent();
    }
}
```

Registring extenssion:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;

@ExtendWith(SkipConditionExtension.class)
public class TestObject {
    @Test
    public void test1() {

    }

    @Test
    @MyAnnotation
    public void test2() {

    }
}
```

Output:

```
INFO: Skipping test
Skipped test: public void com.test.TestObject.test2() by @MyAnnotation
```

**Solution 2, Skip test via invocation interseptor**

[InvocationInterceptor](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-intercepting-invocations) iterface defines the API for Extensions that wish to intercept calls to test.

Current implementation will behave *exactly like your previous* `Rule`.

Extension implementation:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.InvocationInterceptor;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ReflectiveInvocationContext;
import org.junit.platform.commons.logging.Logger;
import org.junit.platform.commons.logging.LoggerFactory;
import org.junit.platform.commons.util.AnnotationUtils;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class SkipCondition implements InvocationInterceptor {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SkipConditionExtension.class);

    @Override
    public void interceptTestMethod(Invocation<Void> invocation, ReflectiveInvocationContext<Method> invocationContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Throwable {
        AnnotatedElement element = extensionContext.getElement().orElse(null);
        if (hasMyAnnotation(element, MyAnnotation.class)) {
            LOGGER.info(() ->"Skipping test");
            invocation.skip();
        } else {
            invocation.proceed();
        }
    }

    private <T extends Annotation>  boolean hasMyAnnotation(final AnnotatedElement element, Class<T> annotation) {
        return element != null && AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(element, annotation).isPresent();
    }
}
```

Registring extenssion:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;

@ExtendWith(SkipCondition.class)
public class TestObject {
    @Test
    public void test1() {

    }

    @Test
    @MyAnnotation
    public void test2() {

    }
}
```

**Please note,** you can perform automatic extension registration according to [documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-automatic).